# Why does restricting GC to 1 thread increase performance?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have some simple java code that I wrote to artificially use a lot of RAM and I find that when I get the associated times when I use these flags:

```
1029.59 seconds .... -Xmx8g -Xms256m
696.44 seconds ..... -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1  -Xmx8g -Xms256m
247.27 seconds ..... -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -Xmx8g -Xms256m
```

Now, I understand why `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` increases performance, but why do I get speedup when I restrict to single threaded GC? Is this an artifact of my poorly written java code or is this something which would apply to properly optimized java as well?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

class xdriver {
  static int N = 100;
  static double pi = 3.141592653589793;
  static double one = 1.0;
  static double two = 2.0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //System.out.println("Program has started successfully\n");

    if( args.length == 1) {
      // assume that args[0] is an integer
      N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }   

    // maybe we can get user input later on this ...
    int nr = N;
    int nt = N;
    int np = 2*N;

    double dr = 1.0/(double)(nr-1);
    double dt = pi/(double)(nt-1);
    double dp = (two*pi)/(double)(np-1);

    System.out.format("nn --> %d\n", nr*nt*np);

    if(nr*nt*np < 0) {
      System.out.format("ERROR: nr*nt*np = %d(long) which is %d(int)\n", (long)( (long)nr*(long)nt*(long)np), nr*nt*np);
      System.exit(1);
    }   

    // inserted to artificially blow up RAM
    double[][] dels = new double [nr*nt*np][3];

    double[] rs = new double[nr];
    double[] ts = new double[nt];
    double[] ps = new double[np];

    for(int ir = 0; ir < nr; ir++) {
      rs[ir] = dr*(double)(ir);
    }   
    for(int it = 0; it < nt; it++) {
      ts[it] = dt*(double)(it);
    }   
    for(int ip = 0; ip < np; ip++) {
      ps[ip] = dp*(double)(ip);
    }   

    double C = (4.0/3.0)*pi;
    C = one/C;

    double fint = 0.0;
    int ii = 0;
    for(int ir = 0; ir < nr; ir++) {
      double r = rs[ir];
      double r2dr = r*r*dr;
      for(int it = 0; it < nt; it++) {
        double t = ts[it];
        double sint = Math.sin(t);
        for(int ip = 0; ip < np; ip++) {
          fint += C*r2dr*sint*dt*dp;

          dels[ii][0] = dr; 
          dels[ii][1] = dt; 
          dels[ii][2] = dp; 
        }   
      }   
    }   

    System.out.format("N ........ %d\n", N);
    System.out.format("fint ..... %15.10f\n", fint);
    System.out.format("err ...... %15.10f\n", Math.abs(1.0-fint));
  }
}
```

Comment: Threads have overhead.  If the code is written in such a way that it won't benefit from additional threads, adding threads will actually slow it down.  If I were to guess, I'd say giving the GC more threads causes it to take up more of your processor's clock cycles, leaving less for your actual program.  Whether this is a good thing or not depends entirely on the nature of the program being executed and the specific speed/memory tradeoffs you're trying to achieve.

Comment: GC is inherently a single-threaded problem. Multiple threads causes a lot more overhead: there has to be a large object graph and a lot of memory to reclaim before adding threads improves performance because you have to overcome that overhead first.

Comment: For real benchmarking it is not sufficient to run your code just once in the main method. Without warmup phase and some iterations to get a mean value and variance, the values are meaningless.

Comment: I run it on varying numbers of input, multiple times, and take the average of my polynomial least squares regression where I know my algorithm is N^3.

Comment: @Laurbert515 OK, well done. But you should also run the algorithm multiple times within the same process (JVM) to do warmup before you measure another several rounds.

Comment: I have seen that done in various application benchmarks, but since the code I'm optimizing for is more likely to be a 'cold start' app, isn't it advantageous to just leave it as a run-once benchmark?

Comment: @Laurbert515 Sure, if optimizing for a very special cold-start situation is your goal. If you want to compare GC strategies instead, you should minimize noise caused by 'accidential' JVM runtime optimiziations.

Comment: A 8GB heap is large enough to benefit from parallel GC. But I think in your case it is mostly scavenger runs. So maybe increasing the new gen would benefit performance and scalability (to threads). I suppose this is not using G1GC but ParOld, check with `java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintGCDetails -version`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not an expert on garbage collectors, so this is probably not the answer you'd like to get, but maybe my findings on your issue are interesting nevertheless.

First of all, I've changed your code into an [JUnit](http://junit.org) test case. Then I've added the [JUnitBenchmarks](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks-tutorial.html) extension from [Carrot Search Labs](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/). It runs JUnit test cases multiple times, measures runtime, and outputs some performance statistics. Most important is the fact that JUnitBenchMarks does 'warmup', i.e. it runs the code several times before actually doing measurement.

The final code I've run:

```
import com.carrotsearch.junitbenchmarks.AbstractBenchmark;
import com.carrotsearch.junitbenchmarks.BenchmarkOptions;
import com.carrotsearch.junitbenchmarks.annotation.BenchmarkHistoryChart;
import com.carrotsearch.junitbenchmarks.annotation.LabelType;

@BenchmarkOptions(benchmarkRounds = 10, warmupRounds = 5)
@BenchmarkHistoryChart(labelWith = LabelType.CUSTOM_KEY, maxRuns = 20)
public class XDriverTest extends AbstractBenchmark {
    static int N = 200;
    static double pi = 3.141592653589793;
    static double one = 1.0;
    static double two = 2.0;

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        // System.out.println("Program has started successfully\n");
        // maybe we can get user input later on this ...
        int nr = N;
        int nt = N;
        int np = 2 * N;

        double dr = 1.0 / (double) (nr - 1);
        double dt = pi / (double) (nt - 1);
        double dp = (two * pi) / (double) (np - 1);

        System.out.format("nn --> %d\n", nr * nt * np);

        if (nr * nt * np < 0) {
            System.out.format("ERROR: nr*nt*np = %d(long) which is %d(int)\n",
                    (long) ((long) nr * (long) nt * (long) np), nr * nt * np);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // inserted to artificially blow up RAM
        double[][] dels = new double[nr * nt * np][4];

        double[] rs = new double[nr];
        double[] ts = new double[nt];
        double[] ps = new double[np];

        for (int ir = 0; ir < nr; ir++) {
            rs[ir] = dr * (double) (ir);
        }
        for (int it = 0; it < nt; it++) {
            ts[it] = dt * (double) (it);
        }
        for (int ip = 0; ip < np; ip++) {
            ps[ip] = dp * (double) (ip);
        }

        double C = (4.0 / 3.0) * pi;
        C = one / C;

        double fint = 0.0;
        int ii = 0;
        for (int ir = 0; ir < nr; ir++) {
            double r = rs[ir];
            double r2dr = r * r * dr;
            for (int it = 0; it < nt; it++) {
                double t = ts[it];
                double sint = Math.sin(t);
                for (int ip = 0; ip < np; ip++) {
                    fint += C * r2dr * sint * dt * dp;

                    dels[ii][0] = dr;
                    dels[ii][5] = dt;
                    dels[ii][6] = dp;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.format("N ........ %d\n", N);
        System.out.format("fint ..... %15.10f\n", fint);
        System.out.format("err ...... %15.10f\n", Math.abs(1.0 - fint));
    }
}
```

As you can see from the benchmark options `@BenchmarkOptions(benchmarkRounds = 10, warmupRounds = 5)`, warmup is done by running the test method 5 times, afterwards the actual benchmark is run 10 times.

Then I run the program above with several different GC options (each with general heap settings of `-Xmx1g -Xms256m`):

- default (no special options)
- `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -Xmx1g -Xms256m`
- `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -Xmx1g -Xms256m`
- `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -Xmx1g -Xms256m`
- `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx1g -Xms256m`
- `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx1g -Xms256m`
- `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx1g -Xms256m`
- `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx1g -Xms256m`

In order to get a summary with chart as HTML page, the following VM arguments have been passed in addition to the GC settings mentioned above:

```
-Djub.consumers=CONSOLE,H2 -Djub.db.file=.benchmarks
-Djub.customkey=[CUSTOM_KEY]
```

(Where `[CUSTOM_KEY]` must be a string that uniquely identifies each benchmark run, e.g. `defaultGC` or `ParallelGCThreads=1`. It is used as label on the axis of the chart).

The following chart summarizes the results:

[image]

```
Run Custom key          Timestamp                   test
1   defaultGC           2015-05-01 19:43:53.796     10.721
2   ParallelGCThreads=1 2015-05-01 19:51:07.79       8.770
3   ParallelGCThreads=2 2015-05-01 19:56:44.985      8.737
4   ParallelGCThreads=4 2015-05-01 20:01:30.071     10.415
5   UseConcMarkSweepGC  2015-05-01 20:03:54.474      2.683
6   UseCCMS,Threads=1   2015-05-01 20:10:48.504      3.856
7   UseCCMS,Threads=2   2015-05-01 20:12:58.624      3.861
8   UseCCMS,Threads=4   2015-05-01 20:13:58.94       2.701
```

System info: CPU: Intel Core 2 Quad Q9400, 2.66 GHz, RAM: 4.00 GB, OS: Windows 8.1 x64, JVM: 1.8.0_05-b13.

*(Note that the individual benchmark runs output more detailled information like standard derivation GC calls and time; unfortunately this information is not available in the summary).*

**Interpretation**

As you can see, there is a huge performance gain when `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` is enabled. The number of threads do not influence the performance that much, and it depends on the general GC strategy if more threads are advantageous or not. The default GC seems to profit from two or three threads, but performance gets worse if four threads are used.

In opposite, *ConcurrentMarkSweep GC* with four threads is more performant than with one or two threads.

So in general, we can't say that more GC threads make performance worse.

Note that I don't know, how many GC threads are used when the default GC or *ConcurrentMarkSweep GC* are used without specifying the number of threads.

Comment: It also depends on how many cores (and cmt) your hardware has.

Comment: @eckes Of course. The tests and its interpretation are valid for the test system only.

Comment: The number of threads relative to physical cores makes a huge difference. Especially when the system has other applications to run too. Once you reach some threshold the scheduler will cause a lot more context-switching which decreases efficiency of the GC.

Answer (score -1):

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2191327

> ParallelGCThreads set the number of threads and possibly cores the GC
>   will use.
>
> If you set this to 8 it can speed up your GC time, however
>   it could mean all your other applications have to stop or will be
>   competing with these threads.
>
> It may be undesirable to have all your
>   applications stop or slow down when any JVM wants to GC.
>
> As such, a
>   setting of 2 may be your best choice. You might find 3 or 4 is fine
>   for your usage pattern (if your JVMs are typically idle) otherwise I
>   suggest, stick with 2.

Comment: That summary is wrong. The application is paused for the GC, thats why you want to finish it as quickly as possible, Most of the time (but not always) this means using all cores is a good idea (unless you run some other programs on the same machine). The explanation is only valid for concurrent collector. Which has its own setting `-XX:CongGCThreads=2`.